# Loading and firing new javascript on .load()

Tags: javascript, jquery

Alright, so, I'm working on building a site that utilizes a basic jQuery `.load()` to call new content into the specified section. Along with that, I have a number of CSS3 based page transitions that make it all run smoothly and look great.

Here is the problem I'm running into. I have, for an example, integrated the cycle2 jQuery plugin into the site. However, when I load a new page, the plugin doesn't run. I need to figure out how to call the script without conflict after the `.load()` completes. Right now, I have all of my jQuery, including the plugin, stored in one JS file, main.js.

Can anyone help me figure out how to make this work? I tried using `$.getScript` as well, but I must not have done it correctly, because it didn't do anything.

Here is the code from main.js for the `load()`...

```
$(document).ready(function(event){
  var isAnimating = false,
      firstLoad   = false;

  $('.menu a').on('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var newPage = $(this).attr('href');
    if( !isAnimating ) changePage(newPage, true);
    firstLoad = true;
  });

  $(window).bind('popstate', function() {
    if(firstLoad) {
      var newPageArray = location.pathname.split('/'),
        newPage = newPageArray[newPageArray.length - 1];
      if( !isAnimating ) changePage(newPage, false);
    }
    firstLoad = true;
  });

  function changePage(url, bool) {
      isAnimating = true;
      $('body').addClass('page-is-changing').removeClass('navigation-open');
      $('#open-button').removeClass('open');
      $('.loader').one('webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend', function(){
        loadNewContent(url, bool);
        $('.loader').off('webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend');
      });

      $('body').on('webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend', function(){
        $(this).delay(5000).queue(function() { 
          $(this).removeClass('load').dequeue();
        });
      }
    );
    if(!transitionsSupported()) loadNewContent(url, bool);
  }

  function loadNewContent(url, bool) {
    var section = $('<div class="wrapper"></div>');
    section.load(url+' .content-wrap > *', function(event){
      $('.wrapper').html(section);
      var delay = ( transitionsSupported() ) ? 1200 : 0;
      setTimeout(function(){
        $('body').removeClass('page-is-changing');
        $('.loader').one('webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend', function(){
          isAnimating = false;
          $('body').addClass('load');
          $('.loader').off('webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend');
        });
        if( !transitionsSupported() ) isAnimating = false;
      }, delay);
      if(url!=window.location && bool){
        window.history.pushState({path: url},'', url);
      }
    });
    console.log(url);
  }

  function transitionsSupported() {
    return $('html').hasClass('csstransitions');
  }

});
```

And [here](http://development.targetedthemovie.com) is the site. Any help would be appreciated, been busting my hump trying to get this figured out for the past two hours.

Comment: If you want to execute JS again after loading additional content, you just have to call the functions in your main.js again after loading.

Comment: @Joerg exactly. How do I do that is the question I'm asking?

Comment: How is `cycle2` called ?

Comment: @guest271314 cycle two is called exclusively through markup, so there's no actual javascript call. http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/demo/basic.php

Comment: @JesseWinton Tried adding `data-*` attributes to new `html` at `section` ?

Comment: @guest271314 to do what exactly?

Comment: If you're dynamically loading new content, you probably have to explicitly call the cycle plugin. The plugin probably hooks into the page load event the first time, but when you load new content the plugin is unaware of that.  Add something like `$( '.mySlideshows' ).cycle();` to your load success handler.

Have a look here: http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/api/ 
Especially the paragraph 'Auto-initialization is not supported for slideshows that are added to the DOM after jQuery's ready event has fired. In this case...'